# Заменить часть строки массива php

Tags: php, массивы, replace

Здравствуйте. В интернете есть туча примеров как заменить значения одного массива на другое. Но нигде (за несколько часов) я не нашёл, как же в массиве заменить только те значения, которые соответствуют определённым критериям.

Вот функции `array_replace` или `str_replace` могут заменить значения одного массива `Array(0=>'odin',1=>'dva',2=>'tri');` на другое `Array(0=>'one',1=>'two',2=>'three');`

Но я никак не могу понять, как же заменить только часть строки, чтоб получилось примерно так:

```
// было так
Array(0=>'odin',1=>'dva',2=>'tri');
// а хочу получить так
Array(0=>'o(d)[i]n',1=>'(d)va',2=>'tr[i]');
```

Т.е. букву `i` заменить на `[i]`, а букву `d` заменить на `(d)`

Единственный вариант, который я могу реализовать, такой (но хотел бы вариант, с регулярками):

```
foreach(Array(0=>'odin',1=>'dva',2=>'tri')as$y=>$z)
{
    // дальше с каждым значением работать отдельно,
    // а после всё собирать в отдельный массив
}
```

Comment: в любом случае, как ни крути с каждым значением вы будете работать отдельно, либо это будет делать используемая вами функция. В чем проблема написать в вашем `foreach` строку вида `data[$y] = str_replace("d", "[d]", $z)` либо аналог с регулярными выражениями, не понятно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php) function, Luke!

```
$arr = ['odin', 'dva', 'tri'];

// array_map проходится по массиву, заменяя значения на возвращённое значение
$arr = array_map(function($el){
  // Заменяем все d и i
  return preg_replace_callback("/d|i/", function($found){
    return $found[0] === 'd' ? '(d)' : '[i]';
  }, $el);
}, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

https://repl.it/FEIG/0

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо!

Comment: @dgdhsk, Всегда пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Use str_replace;

```
$arr = Array(0=>"odin",1=>"dva",2=>"tri");
foreach ($arr as $r=>$z) 
{
  $arr[$r] = str_replace("i","[i]",$z);
  $arr[$r] = str_replace("d","(d)",$arr[$r]);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но такой вариант у меня уже был.

Comment: Рад стараться :)